# Custom Kite python libraries

Tags: python, pycharm, kite

I have just started using kite by integrating it in Pycharm but I want to use custom libraries. So, how do I upload libraries to kite database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently released a new feature for this, and have published [help docs](https://help.kite.com/article/97-adding-libraries-from-pythonpath-to-the-kite-index) that we'll continue updating. Here are the instructions for how you can add libraries (incl. custom libraries) to Kite's directory so you're sure the libraries get indexed by Kite.

First, make the /libraries directory in the .kite directory if it's not already there:

```
mkdir -p ~/.kite/libraries/
```

Next, create a symbolic link to the library you want indexed by Kite:

```
ln -s /your_lib_dir/ ~/.kite/libraries/
```

Finally, check the link is there:

```
cd .kite/
ls libraries/your_lib_dir/
```

Kite will then be able to index those specified libraries.

(We're debugging some aspects of this, so let us know if you run into issues or have further questions: support[at]kite.com.)